# AWS EMR CLI - Pass Arguments to HIVE

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, arguments, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I am using aws' emr ruby cli to generate Hadoop clusters and I am trying to include arguments to use within a HIVE script hosted elsewhere like so:

```
./elastic-mapreduce --create ... --args -d,DT=2013-01-26
```

'DT' shows up satisfactorily in my HadoopJarStep.Args array, so I try to include it in the HIVE script like so:

```
...

tblproperties(
  'dynamodb.table.name' = ${DT},
  ...
```

but I quickly get this:

```
Parse Error: line 8:28 mismatched input '$' expecting StringLiteral near '=' in specifying key/value property
```

How should I properly include the argument in my HIVE script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your current approach isn't working, but I've been successful with:

```
./elastic-mapreduce --create ... --args "-hiveconf,DT=2013-01-26"
```

and in the hive script:

```
tblproperties(
    "dynamodb.table.name" = "${hiveconf:DT}",
    ...
)
```

Hope this helps.